# only one checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

where you can add contacts. And a contact has a email address and several checkboxes.
I try to validate on checkboxes. If only a specific checkbox is checked then it is allowed to fill in the same email address as contactperson1.

so if you make a contact then it is the first contact. You create a second one, then it is contact2.. etc.

The checkbox is like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="required checkTotal 
        contactpersonen_canseestock_0" 
        value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseestock_0" 
        id="contactpersonen_canseestock_2">
</input>
<label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseestock_0">
     Mag goederen afhalen
</label>
```

the jquery is like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen_email",function(value) {
       if ($(".contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(":checked") && $('#formid :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
            console.log("checkbox true");
            return true;

        }
        else{
            console.log("checkbox not true");
            return false;
        }
    }, "Email adres bestaat al");

    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkTotal = { checkTotal: true };

    $("#idform").validate();
```

but now every time it says: Email already exists.

Thank you

Comment: provide a complete working example (jsfiddle/codepen/snippet).

Comment: working exampl? I dont have that. That's why I ask

Comment: working example that demonstrates the problem... it's impossible to "run" your current code.